# C# - Excel Number Formatting Issue with International settings

Tags: c#, excel, interop, formatting, numbers

I am trying to write to an Excel 2003 spreadsheet using c# 3.5. However I am unable to get this to function correctly across different country settings. The country settings are either English or German. These two settings have different decimal and thousands settings. Everything works fine unless a user has changed the decimal and thousands separators in the International settings of the Options screen. Can anybody help as I feel I can no longer see the wood for the trees and am missing something obvious.

Summary:

Data retrieved from an access database.
Read by c# application and written to an Excel spreadsheet.

Excel Version 2003
Machines are either English or German.
It is possible that decimal and thousands separators have been changed within the International Settings options in Excel -- This is where the problem occurs.

Observed behaviour:
English setup with default Options --> International - as expected
German setup with default Options --> International- as expected

English setup with decimal separator changed to ",", thousands separator set to "." and System Separators unticked in Options --> International - Excel data incorrect. See asterisked rows.

Data                    Excel

3706888.0300            3706888.03
2587033.8000            2587033.8
2081071.1800            2081071.18
9030160.3333            90.301.603.333**
42470.9842              424.709.842**
4465546.2800            4465546.28
1436037.3200            1436037.32
111650.0000             111650
2567007.0833            25.670.070.833**

I have attcahed sample code to demonstrate this behaviour. If anybody can show me what I am doing wrong, it would be much appreciated.

To run this code sample, just create a new Windows forms application and post the code below into Form1.cs. You will also need to add a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.

Many Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading; 
using System.Globalization;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void ExportDTToExcel()
        {

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            app.Visible = true;
            Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
            Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)wb.ActiveSheet;


            string culture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString();//"en-GB";
            CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(culture);

            string excelGroupSeparator = app.ThousandsSeparator.ToString();
            string excelDecimalSeparator = app.DecimalSeparator.ToString();
            bool systemseparators = app.UseSystemSeparators  ;
            if (app.UseSystemSeparators == false)
            {
                app.DecimalSeparator = ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
                app.ThousandsSeparator = ci.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator;
                //ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = app.DecimalSeparator;
                //ci.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = app.ThousandsSeparator;
            }
            //app.DecimalSeparator = ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
            //app.ThousandsSeparator = ci.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator;


            app.UseSystemSeparators = true;


            // Content.   

            try
            {
                SetCellValue("3706888.0300", ws, 0, 0, ci);
                SetCellValue("2587033.8000", ws, 1, 0, ci);
                SetCellValue("2081071.1800", ws, 2, 0, ci);
                SetCellValue("9030160.3333", ws, 3, 0, ci);
                SetCellValue("42470.9842", ws, 4, 0, ci);
                SetCellValue("4465546.2800", ws, 5, 0, ci);
                SetCellValue("1436037.3200", ws, 6, 0, ci);
                SetCellValue("111650.0000", ws, 7, 0, ci);
                SetCellValue("2567007.0833", ws, 8, 0, ci);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {


                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);

            }

            //wb.SaveAs(Filepath, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            //wb.Close(false, Type.Missing, false);
            app.DecimalSeparator = excelDecimalSeparator;
            app.ThousandsSeparator = excelGroupSeparator;
            app.UseSystemSeparators = systemseparators;
            //app.Quit();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wb);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ws);
            app = null;
            wb = null;
            ws = null;


        }

        private static void SetCellValue(string data, Worksheet ws,int row, int col, CultureInfo ci)
        {


                double val;
                try
                {
                    val = Convert.ToDouble(data);
                    Console.WriteLine(val);

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                    //Util.Log("Null Value ignored.", LogType.ERROR);
                    return;
                }

                try
                {
                    string s = val.ToString();
                    ws.Cells[row + 2 , col + 1] = s;

                    //Util.Log("S:" + s, LogType.ERROR);
                }
                catch
                {
                    //Util.Log("Null Value ignored.", LogType.ERROR);
                }
            }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            ExportDTToExcel();
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have just scanned your code and was wondering why you have `CultureInfo ci` as input for the method `SetCellValue` because you are not using it...

Answer (score 4):

I haven't run your code, just scanned it...

First potential Problem:  You are checking UseSystemSeparators and then setting the DecimalSeparaor and ThousandsSeparator.

```
        if (app.UseSystemSeparators == false)
        {
            app.DecimalSeparator = ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
            app.ThousandsSeparator = ci.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator;
        }
```

Then right after, you are turning on SystemSeparators, so the code above is not doing anything since you are turning the system seperators on.

```
        app.UseSystemSeparators = true;
```

Second potential problem/suggestion:
When setting the cell value, set it as a double value instead of string, let Excel format the number for you.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I have cleaned up the code and I have now got it working having removed some of the unnecessary lines. I've incorporated it into my code and the test team is now giving it it a good bash. I will post the working version below. C# is not my first language so, although the code works, I am always open to ways to improve it.

Answer (score 3):

Excel used over COM has several restrictions most important ones to respect are:

- Use the en-US culture ([LCID bug](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320369))
- Call all the methods from one and the same Thread (set to the right culture "en-US")

Then you'll get rid of most sporadic crashes regarding Excel automation & localization.

Answer (score 2):

[This KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320369/en-us), and a couple of other KB articles it links to, describe some of the localization issues you may hit when automating Excel from .NET.

It may help explain your problem

Comment: Thanks Joe.

The article you linked included something that I overlooked initially. It seems that (in conjunction with a suggestion below from Chris) I needed to declare the Workbook and Worksheet objects after setting the CultureInfo.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Chris and Joe, I finally got the code to work as desired.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading; 
using System.Globalization;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void ExportDTToExcel()
        {

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            app.Visible = true;

            string culture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString();//"en-GB";
            CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(culture);

            bool systemseparators = app.UseSystemSeparators  ;
            if (app.UseSystemSeparators == false)
            {

                app.UseSystemSeparators = true;

            }

            // Content.   
            Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
            Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)wb.ActiveSheet;            
            try
            {
                SetCellValue("3706888.0300", ws, 0, 0, ci);
                SetCellValue("2587033.8000", ws, 1, 0, ci);
                SetCellValue("2081071.1800", ws, 2, 0, ci);
                SetCellValue("9030160.3333", ws, 3, 0, ci);
                SetCellValue("42470.9842", ws, 4, 0, ci);
                SetCellValue("4465546.2800", ws, 5, 0, ci);
                SetCellValue("1436037.3200", ws, 6, 0, ci);
                SetCellValue("111650.0000", ws, 7, 0, ci);
                SetCellValue("2567007.0833", ws, 8, 0, ci);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {


                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);

            }

            app.UseSystemSeparators = systemseparators;
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wb);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ws);
            app = null;
            wb = null;
            ws = null;
        }

        private static void SetCellValue(string data, Worksheet ws,int row, int col, CultureInfo ci)
        {
                double val;
                try
                {
                    val = Convert.ToDouble(data);
                    Console.WriteLine(val);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                    //Util.Log("Null Value ignored.", LogType.ERROR);
                    return;
                }

                try
                {
                    string s = val.ToString();
                    ws.Cells[row + 2 , col + 1] = s;

                    //Util.Log("S:" + s, LogType.ERROR);
                }
                catch
                {
                    //Util.Log("Null Value ignored.", LogType.ERROR);
                }
            }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            ExportDTToExcel();
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }


    }
}
```