# Excel locale wrong time formating

Tags: c#, excel

i have very weird problem with excel. I have two files , each file has only one column which is date, using c# interoop libraries I am opening each file and save as csv. If I open each excel , then time format is dd/MM/YYYY but now whats happen, after saving to csv one excel has the same time format which is dd/MM/YYYY but the other one has MM/dd/YYYY , how is this possible ?

This is code to save as csv:

```
   var application = new Application();
    var workbooks = application.Workbooks;
    var workbook = workbooks.Open(file);


    application.DisplayAlerts = false;

    var tempFile = file.Substring(0, file.Length - 4) + ".csv";

    if (File.Exists(tempFile))
        Directory.Delete(tempFile);

    workbook.SaveAs(tempFile, XlFileFormat.xlCSVWindows);
    Extensions.DisposeExcel(workbook, application, workbooks, null, null);
```

I don't set any localisation in the application. Maybe worth to mention is that one excel has xlsx extenstaion and the other one (whis is flipping day with month) is much older with xls.

One more thing, I've noticed that when I save these excel as csv using excel save as, then all is fine.

Comment: And what are the regional date settings in your computer? It can happen that excel is confusing month with day.

Comment: BE-be , but as I said there are two excels, one is ok the other has inverted day with month after saving to csv.

Comment: pls specify what excel file did work correctly. xlsx or the xls?

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz please read my question again, all is there.

Comment: @PortlandRunner sorry, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did an example concerning your described problem. I used your code (adapted it a bit) and two Excel-files. Unfortunatelly I could not reproduce your problem.

```
// call the method with .xlsx and .xls file.
//export2Csv(@"e:\temp\demoNEW.xlsx");
//export2Csv(@"e:\temp\demoOLD.xls");

private static void export2Csv(string fileName)
{
    string csvFile = Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, "csv");

    var application = new Application();
    var workbooks = application.Workbooks;
    var workbook = workbooks.Open(fileName);

    application.DisplayAlerts = false;

    // ATTENTION!! german number format, must be adapted to your locale culture/language
    workbook.ActiveSheet.Range["A1", "A65535"].NumberFormat = "TT/MM/JJJJ hh:mm:ss";  

    workbook.SaveAs(csvFile, XlFileFormat.xlCSVWindows);

    // clean up Excel - I think Extensions.DisposeExcel(..) does the same?!
    application.Quit();
    workbook = null;
    application = null;
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();
}
```

First I created a .xlsx file and entered some dates (1.1.2014 to 31.1.2014 german format) and afterwards saved it as .xls file.

When running my code **both files created the same result in dd/MM/yyyy**. I did some background check too.

- [MSDN Globalization Excel Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157877.aspx) states that

> Whenever a managed client calls a method on a COM object and it needs
>   to pass in culture-specific information, it does so using the
>   CurrentCulture (locale) that matches the current thread locale. The
>   current thread locale is inherited from the user's regional settings
>   by default.

- within [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914643/determine-excel-version-culture-via-microsoft-office-interop-excel) I found a question&answer *Determine Excel Language* that shows how to display current system culture and excel UI culture

check this snippet

```
CultureInfo cSystemCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
CultureInfo cExcelCulture = new CultureInfo(application.LanguageSettings.get_LanguageID(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAppLanguageID.msoLanguageIDUI));

Console.WriteLine(cSystemCulture);
Console.WriteLine(cExcelCulture);
```

- Some posts [SO ExcelNumberFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362315/c-sharp-excel-number-formatting-issue-with-international-settings) describe a *solution* to call all code from one and the same thread and cultureInfo **en-US**
- others recommend to format each cell with a certain numberFormat (see [social.msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/253b580d-6103-4fbf-a650-8eaad1f3ee56/interopexcel-set-date-format?forum=csharpgeneral) )

So not quite a solution, but I hope at least some good hints for you.

In case none of these points helps you out, you could still send me your .xlsx and .xls files to franz.pilgerstorfer@gmx.at and I will have a further look into)

**EDIT**
According to the given files, I found the answer to your problem. Your file `right.xls` is an Excel file, but your file `wrong.xls` contains HTML markup. So the only problem is the wrong file extension!

`wrong.xls` should be renamed to `wrong.html`!

Saying that, I tried to figure out, how my code could work despite the fact that there are two different input files. So I changed my code (already edited above) and added a line to **manually set the number format**.

```
// ATTENTION!! german number format, must be adapted to your locale culture/language
workbook.ActiveSheet.Range["A1", "A65535"].NumberFormat = "TT/MM/JJJJ hh:mm:ss";
```

After that, both input files printed out the same dateTime format.

Comment: please give my your mail addres or send me it to mine : obibezfobi@gmail.com and I will send you these two files.

Comment: see my answer: franz.pilgerstorfer@gmx.at

Comment: thanks really thanks, anyway this wrong file was generated by some website where I put download file and xls file was downloaded so I am a bit surrprise that this is html file, by anyway thanks, really thanks.