# Get Exact format string with respect to given format specifier

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

There are lot of format specifier in .net e.g. C for currency, D for decimal.
Lot of defined formats can be [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx).

How can I get exact format behind format specifier as per given locale.

E.g. (I assume here en-US locale)

**GetFormatSpecifierText("C")** should return me **"$" #,##0.00**

**GetFormatSpecifierText("F")** should return me **"#,##0.00**

Comment: You can use [custom number format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Actually i need to pass desire format to excel. So if i get **"$" #,##0.00**, then i can easily pass into excel and it would get converted to currency. But if i pass some value (eg $ 100.00) then it would get treated as string (this is not my requirement). Further i don't know what would be custom format, so i want to extract at run time.

Comment: I found something like **NumberFormatinfo.CurrencyPositivePattern**. But it gives me some 'int' value. Seeking to get something which return me string pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Look at how Culture is used in combination with the format specifiers. I believe you may be looking for the override in the below [code from MSDN:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/syy068tk(v=vs.90).aspx)

```
public class userOverrideSample
{
   [WebMethod]
   public String UserLocalSetting()
   {
      int i = 100;

      // Sets the CurrentCulture to French in France.
      Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
      // Displays i formatted as currency for the CurrentCulture.
      // Due to operating system differences, you cannot be sure what currency
      // symbol will be used.
      return (i.ToString("c"));
   }   

   [WebMethod]
   public String OverrideUserSetting()
   {
      int i = 100;

      // Sets the CurrentCulture to French in France.
      // Uses the CultureInfo constructor that takes a 
      // useUserOverride parameter.
      // Sets the useUserOverride value to false.
      Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR", _
         false);
      // Displays i formatted as currency for the CurrentCulture.
      // This will override any user settings and display the euro symbol.
      return (i.ToString("c"));
   }
}
```

Comment: Actually i need to pass desire format to excel. So if i get **"$" #,##0.00**, then i can easily pass into excel and it would get converted to currency. But if i pass some value (eg $ 100.00) then it would get treated as string (this is not my requirement).

Comment: Excel is also culture aware. How are you "passing it to Excel" - are you using automation - if so, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362315/c-sharp-excel-number-formatting-issue-with-international-settings

Comment: Correct Murray, but in case of currency it get constant. If I pass fr-FR for currency conversion and doing code in en-US, how can we write exact Currency formatted string (which must be in currency format and arithmetic operation operable) in to excel? That's why I am asking for format pattern string. By the way I have implemented for currency for me with some tricky solution. Thanks for answer and comments.

Comment: @NeoAsh if you cant find a cleaner way to do it, then you can calculate the format string from a culture's NumberFormatInfo :   NumberFormatInfo nfi = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat;
            Console.WriteLine(nfi.<choose property>);

Answer (score 0):

I write below code to get currency format pattern.

Here, passed param numberFormat as **[Currency]#,##0.00** and **fr-FR** locale; and got **# ##0,00 "€"** as desire and expected o/p.

```
static string[] CurrencyPositivePattern = { "$n", "n$", "$ n", "n $" };
static string[] CurrencyNegativePattern = { "($n)", "-$n", "$-n", "$n-", "(n$)", 
                        "-n$", "n-$", "n$-", "-n $", "-$ n",
                        "n $-", "$ n-", "$ -n", "n- $", "($ n)",
                        "(n $)" };

    internal static string GetCurrencyPattern(System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo numberFormatInfo, string numberFormat)
    {
        numberFormat = numberFormat.Replace("[Currency]", string.Empty);
        int pos = numberFormatInfo.CurrencyPositivePattern;
        int neg = numberFormatInfo.CurrencyNegativePattern;
        string currencySymbol = string.Format("\"{0}\"", numberFormatInfo.CurrencySymbol);
        string excelPattern = string.Concat(CurrencyPositivePattern[pos].Replace("n", numberFormat).Replace("$", currencySymbol),
            ";",
             CurrencyNegativePattern[neg].Replace("n", numberFormat).Replace("$", currencySymbol));
        return excelPattern;
    }
```

Few References that I used for implementation:
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencypositivepattern(v=vs.110).aspx

As I stucked at specific **Currency** format for excel, I write Currency specific code. Others formats are easily handled by excel (same also commented by **Murray Foxcroft** in answer's comment).